# Is my contact form with PHPMailer and OVH SMTP code secured enough? How to use environment variable with OVH

Tags: environment-variables, phpmailer, ovh

I'm using OVH to host my website, the cheapest hosting plan: Kimsufi 2015.

I have a contact form which is working but I wonder about the security using PHPMailer.
My contact form works fine, a user is able to send me an email. However, I expose my SMTP configuration data in a PHP file:

```
    $mail->Host = 'ssl0.ovh.net';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'contact@domain.fr';
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;
```

Normally, a normal user can't access this file, since it's a PHP file, accessible only on the server side. Am I being paranoid or is this secure enough?

I've heard of setting an environment variable. When I upload my files (with FTP through Filezilla), in my WWW folder I saw that there was an .htaccess file (I don't know why it's there), so I tried adding my environment variables to it:

```
SetEnv SMTP_USERNAME contact@domain.fr
SetEnv SMTP_PASSWORD mypassword
```

Then I modified my SMTP configuration:

```
$mail->Username = getenv('SMTP_USERNAME');
$mail->Password = getenv('SMTP_PASSWORD');
```

It didn't work, I get a "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.SMTP server error: QUIT command failed".

Otherwise, by doing a Google search with the keywords "ovh" and "environment variable", I came across the article: https://help.ovhcloud.com/csm/en-web-paas-bestpractices-environment-build?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0053653

But I don't think it concerns me because the file ".platform.app.yaml, located at the root of your application folder inside your Git repository." (cf https://help.ovhcloud.com/csm/en-ie-web-paas-setting-up-configuration-app?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0053697) I'm not using Git here.

I saw that there was an .ovhconfig file outside the WWW folder but it doesn't seem to be that.
Do you have any clues? I want to use environment variables Thanks for your help.